# Is the function app (azure) able to access a folder in a remote vm?

Tags: azure, azure-function-app

- What is the problem?

  I have created a function app which creates some files under path `D:\home\site\wwwroot\afolder`. What I need is the function app to copy and paste these files to a remote server (VM in Azure) under a specific folder in the VM.
- What I tried :

  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet

Based on the above documentation, a function app can access resources in remote network with vnet integration - it is like declaring to the function app that it will be under the same vnet as the VM and then it would hopefully be able to access the resources / folder of the remote VM. (no luck)

Based on their documentation:

> There are some things that VNet Integration doesn't support including: Mounting a drive

I am not sure if I can achieve what I need with the vnet integration after all.

So the question is: can I copy & paste the files created by the function app to a remote VM folder and if yes in which way?

Comment: Hi, have you considered Azure Files as a storage option, you can write to it from the function and also mount the Files folder on your VM?

Comment: Hi Simon and thanks for your feedback. Yes this is the workaround i have think of - to create a file share which function app has access to and then through this the server will have access to these files with the mount to the drive but i don't like it as i need the mapping to be with a folder under a specific path not a drive. Moreover this solution would require a script to transfer the files from the mount to the folder i need but surely it can work as a solution.

Comment: Hi, no problem, can you not create a symlink on the VM from the desired folder to the mounted fileshare to get around the script to transfer the file? Only other thing I can think of is if you have an SCP library you can use to transfer the files in code from the function, that would then require either setting up ssh keys or storing a user/password in say a KeyVault and transferring them from the function that way

Comment: symlink is an interesting option. I will check and reply back. Thanks

Comment: The response from Microsoft was that ASE is an alternative instead of using VNet integration (even though a little expensive ). Adding here the link for those who want to learn more about it... learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro .Also suggested that they plan to bring this functionality (Routing tables with VNet integration) in the future!